# Using a dynamic class

Tags: php, symfony

I have a query that looks like this:

```
$query = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Personal::class)->data('p.uid, p.' . $column, $column, $value);
```

I would like `Personal` to be dynamic. So I tried it with:

```
$table = 'Personal';
$query = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository($table::class)->data('p.uid, p.' . $column, $column, $value);
```

But that doesn't work, so I get the error message:

> Compile Error: Dynamic class names are not allowed in compile-time
>   ::class fetch

How can I make it dynamic?

Comment: If you have the class name in the variable `$table`, can't you just use that? How and where is the variable defined?

Comment: Why would someone downvote this question ?! it's a clear, defined problem with minimal reproducible code that is answerable with a clear-cut answer that requires knowledge more than effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getRepository()` expects a string containing the class name, which `Personal::class` gives you. So, you can just use the variable directly:

```
->getRepository($table)
```

Depending on your code layout, you may have to add your namespace:

```
->getRepository('My\\Repository\\Namespace\\' . $table)
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```php
$table = 'Personal';
$query = $this->getDoctrine()
         ->getRepository(get_class(new $table))
         ->data('p.uid, p.' . $column, $column, $value);
```

Comment: If `$table` already contains the name of the class, why wouldn't you just use that directly instead of instantiating the class and run `get_class()` on it? Wouldn't you just get back the same string you started with?

Comment: i think you didn't notice the use of `new` keywork to make it an instance of object.
Also, i don't think its pointless because you will get the full namespace returned by the function.